# Ansible list gives deprecation warning

Tags: ansible

I have created an Ansible playbook for updating iLO firmware, and it works fine.  However it gives me a comma separated values for a list has been deprecated warning (none of my other playbooks give this warning).  I am assuming this has to to with the iLO_Models variable, so I have tried changing the variable to have just one model and still get the warning.

Ansible version is 2.3.2.0.  I would just like to fix my code to remove the warning and ensure it does not break.

```
---
- name: iLO Firmware Upgrade for Standalone Servers
  hosts: testing
  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset: hardware
  become: true
  vars:
    firmware_directory: /firmware
    iLO4: iLO4-2.54-CP032620.scexe
    iLO4_Models:
      - 'ProLiant DL320e Gen8 v2'
      - 'ProLiant DL380 Gen9'
      - 'ProLiant DL580 G9'
      - 'ProLiant BL460c Gen8'
      - 'ProLiant BL460c Gen9'
  tasks:
    - name: Copy iLO4 update
      copy: >
           src={{ firmware_directory }}/{{ iLO4 }}
           dest=/tmp/
           owner=root
           group=root
           mode=0640
      when: ansible_product_name in iLO4_Models

    - name: Install iLO4 Update
      shell: /bin/bash /tmp/{{ iLO4 }} -s
      when: ansible_product_name in iLO4_Models
      register: ilo_result
      changed_when: ilo_result.rc == 0
      failed_when: ilo_result.rc == 1 or ilo_result.rc == 4
```

I get the following warning:

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Using comma separated values for a list has been deprecated. You should instead use the correct YAML syntax for lists. .
This feature will be removed in a future release. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting 
deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of `gather_subset: hardware`.

Replace with:

```
gather_subset: [hardware]
```

or:

```
gather_subset:
  - hardware
```